# Error initializing Cytoscape with TypeScript and Rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, cytoscape.js, rollupjs

I'm trying to initialize Cytoscape.js for an [obsidian plugin](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api). I've imported Cytoscape as follows: `import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';`, and I'm calling it a bit later using `const viz = cytoscape();`.

This compiles without errors using rollup, but then crashes on loading the code with the following error. Note that `cytoscape()`is never itself called. Would anyone know how to resolve such an import error?

```
app.js:1 Plugin failure: neo4j-graph-view TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'remove' of object '[object Object]'
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1), <anonymous>:13973:17)
    at e.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at app.js:1
    at Object.next (app.js:1)
    at a (app.js:1)
```

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "es2015",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "scripthost",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
//    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

My rollup.config.js

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import {nodeResolve} from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

export default {
  input: 'main.ts',
  output: {
    dir: '.',
    sourcemap: 'inline',
    format: 'cjs',
    exports: 'default',
  },
  external: ['obsidian'],
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    nodeResolve({browser: true}),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    copy({
      targets: [
        {src: 'main.js', dest: '../../semantic-obsidian/Semantic Obsidian/.obsidian/plugins/neo4j-graph-view'},
      ],
      hook: 'writeBundle',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this somehow, this crash happened because Cytoscape.js edits `Array.prototype`. However, the current version of Obsidian changed something in `Array.prototype` and then made it readonly. They'll fix this, which should allow normal importing of Cytoscape.